# Having trouble setting up used iMac, Mac OS X Start Disk won't eject

Tags: disk-utility, imac, snow-leopard

I just got an iMac from a friend and tried starting it up on the Mac OS X Start Disk. But following the instruction to install Snow Leopard, I can't install it onto Macintosh HD (which is the only disk option), and the Mac OS X Start Disk is also stuck. Going through Disk Utility to eject it displays an error "make sure that all applications and files are closed on this disk." Using commands to eject also fail. I also can't connect to my network (not sure if that would help with any issues) because it wants a username and password, and typing in only the password results in "connection failed."
I honestly have no clue what I'm doing anymore. Please help.

Comment: Reboot it while holding down the left mouse button and it will eject the CD, assuming there's not a physical problem with the drive.

Comment: Can you [identify your iMac model](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201634#:~:text=Find%20the%20serial%20number%20printed,page%20to%20find%20your%20model.)? Do you have any other computers available? If so, can post which operating systems are installed? Usually, you can make an installer flash drive with the latest version of OS X/macOS that is compatible with your iMac.

Comment: what is `Mac OS X Start Disk`

Comment: Mac computer with an Intel processor
1GB of memory
5GB of available disk space
DVD drive for installation
Some features require a compatible Internet service provider; fees may apply.

Comment: It's quite difficult to tell exactly what you've done so far & precisely what went wrong. If you're booted from the DVD, then it won't eject because it's in use. You need to tell us which instructions you're following, at what step it went wrong & exactly what the error was.

Comment: If – and only if – holding/repeat clicking left mouse button during the boot process doesn't work, you can also try pushing the unfolded end of a paperclip into a small hole to force the disk to eject. From memory the hole is at the bottom of the disc slot on the model of iMac you probably have. Do this while the computer is on, and be extra careful not to damage the disk or any part of the optical drive itself. This discussion might help https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6436708?sortBy=best